# How to reset blocks count in bitcoin-cli regtest?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

How can I reset the block count value or fully restart the regtest?

Now `getblockcount` command returns me a `6120`.

```
$ bitcoin-cli getblockcount
6120
```

After reloading `bitcoind` the `getblockcount` value not resets to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to just delete the `regtest` subdirectory inside the `.bitcoin` folder

> You can safely delete the `regtest` subdirectory and restart Bitcoin Core to start a new regtest

https://developer.bitcoin.org/examples/testing.html